# Can you get back into Safeword?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

During the mission Return to Steelport, you need to go to a club named Safeword to rescue Zimos. Are you only able access Safeword during this mission, or is it also possible to return and run around in there after this mission?

Comment: I don't yet own SR3, but in SR2 you could get back into most places afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get back into the area you were in during the mission.  Later in the game you'll unlock it as a crib (at the end of the Zimos mission line).  However, you're in a different part of the building, the penthouse area from what I can tell.  You can, however, upgrade it to a majestic, purple tower displaying your dominance over the Morningstar's territory.

Comment: I was disappointed that you couldn't actually run around in the same area you were in for the mission. :(

Comment: Admit it, you just wanted a pony.

Comment: I wish *my* ponies pulled me on rickshaws in the street...

Answer (score 1):

A while further down the storyline you wind up taking over the place and setting it up as another Stronghold.

Answer (score -1):

You can be in the same area you were in.  Enter the cheat `givesonic`.  That will give you the sonic boom weapon. Blast the front doors, and they open.